# How can I cache data in Flutter when there is no internet?

Tags: flutter, caching, hive

I am sending data to Firebase in the application I developed with Flutter. However, when there is no internet, I want to cache this data and send it to the service in the background when the internet is available. how can I do that?

The data I will send is a small num data

Comment: Use share_prefrences for small key-value pairs and hive for larger data models to cache data locally

Comment: I thought about that, but in a scenario where the internet is available, I couldn't think of how to delete it from the memory after making a request again and discarding that data

Comment: use equatable to compare object properties, for example in a class named Person you have login_time and username and wallet_amount, you can compare 2 people's usernames, and if there is a new version in the server, clear the cache and restore the new value.

Comment: I solved it like this:
I saved the data using SharedPref with the stream in Connectivity Plus when there was no internet connection. When the internet came back on, I sent it in the background. Thanks for your recommendations